# Draw wireframe models for Gear VR app: Unity or Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, model, wireframe

I want to create a 3D Android app for Gear VR that does/lets me do the following:

1. Read an input file with a bunch of coordinates of points (including
   information about how they should be connected)
2. Draw a wireframe model with these points
3. Walk around and through the model in first person to look at it from different angles using a gamepad/controller. I don't want to directly interact with it!
4. (Maybe have more than one model displayed at the same time, including filled ones)

The question is: Is it possible to draw 3D wireframe models in Unity using coordinates instead of using already finished models that were created in Blender/Maya/...?

I already programmed 2D Android apps in Java + Eclipse but I'm new to the whole VR thing, plus I don't know C#. Would you recommend using Unity or Eclipse for my app?

Answer (score 0):

go for Unity for sure. everything is much simpler for vr in Unity.

and here is your wireframe shader on unity asset store:

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21897

Comment: That's sadly not what I'm looking for. The thing is that I want my app to read an e.g. txt file with coordinates for the points. The app then has to draw the points, connect them according to what it says in the file and create a wireframe model like that. I don't want to/can't create a model in e.g. Blender beforehand and then use a shader to make it look like a wireframe model because the coordinates are different, depending on what you write in the text file, of course.

Comment: oh yes you can do that as well, 2 ways that come off the top of my head: 1. using Unity's LineRenderers. LineRenderer takes Vector3 array and draws a line from 0th point to the last. Unity batches different mashes into one if they use same material so even if you have 1000 LineRenderer with same material it's gonna be fine. second way would be constructing mesh by hand using the Mesh class. Basically you build a mesh in runtime and use the provided shader. (I'd go for the second way, it's more fun)

Comment: Just checked out the documentation for LineRenderers and having it draw everything as a possible continuous line on its own sounds awesome! Not sure if the Mesh class would be useful, though, since I can't guarantee that there's even going to be a closed mesh (including triangles) and not something like e.g. a name in crusiv handwriting. I'll look into both, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Miguel12345 made a package that build the wireframe with uvs instead of the geometry shader (not supported on some mobile phones). You get the package [here on Github](https://github.com/miguel12345/UnityWireframeRenderer). Props to him!